# freebsd and eclipse - setting the ide up for debugging

Tags: eclipse, path, installation, freebsd

After downloading the freebsd source code from svn and loading it into eclipse, the indexer cannot find a lot of symbols.
But I still can jump to the declaration/definition of some symbols.

I checked the indexer, which is on. I rebuilt it.
Everything is checked in the indexer pane except the "skip..."

But still no luck.

The same project works beautifully under linux with no modification. It fails under osx yosemite (I installed the command line tool and all the bells).

Can you give me a tip ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is how to get full set of FreeBSD source code?

Comment: No I edit the question to make it clearer